# Getting block matrices to be the same size

Tags: matrices, block

I want to produce equations with block matrices

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\rdots}{\hspace{.2ex}\raisebox{1ex}{\rotatebox{-12}{$\ddots$}}}


\begin{document}


\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{align}
 \begin{blockarray}{(cccc|cccc)}
  1 &  & 0 & \cdots & \BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$0$}}\\
   & \rdots &  &  & & & &\\
  0 &  &  1 &  & & & &\\
  \vdots &  &  & \rdots & & & &\\
  \cline{1-8}
& & &  & 1 &  &  & \cdots \\
\BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$0$}} & & \rdots  &  \\
& & & & 0 &  & 1 &  \\
& & & & \vdots &  &  &\rdots \\
 \end{blockarray}+
 \begin{blockarray}{(cccc|cccc)}
  \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$0$}} &  \BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$S-T$}}  \\
    &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
   &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
     &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
  \cline{1-8}
  \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$T-S$}} & \BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{\huge$0$}}   \\
   &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
   &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
   &     &   &   &    &   &   &   & \\
 \end{blockarray}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

My code produces the correct matrices, but they are not the same size:
[image]

the one on the lefthand size (with the S-T) is smaller! I don't get why, can anyone help?

Comment: Why not simply using something like `\[
\huge
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
I & 0 \\
\hline
0 & I
\end{array}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & S-T \\
\hline
T-S & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\]` (with a possible remark explaining that `I` denotes an identity matrix of the given size)? This is more concise and looks a lot better (in my opinion).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly simpler approach, omitting the unsightly internal rules in the matrices, and using a `scalebox` to shrink the identity matrix instead of trying to grow the other parts.  The other trick used here is to insert an invisible vertical rule to control the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\IM}{\scalebox{0.7}{\(\begin{matrix}1&0&\cdots\\0&1\\\vdots&&\ddots\end{matrix}\)}}
\newcommand{\BigO}{\vrule width 0pt height 17pt depth 15pt 0}
\[
    \left( \begin{matrix} \IM & \BigO \\ \BigO & \IM \end{matrix} \right)
    +
    \left( \begin{matrix} \BigO & S-T \\ T-S & \BigO \end{matrix} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some invisible character to control spacing, but could not find one that worked in math mode. Anyway, I noticed that what makes the first matrix is bigger are the dots, the seems to take up more room than regular characters. Gonna try your solution.